# is there a way to make a flashlight that cannot go through solid objects in game maker

Tags: game-maker

I am making a 2D (top-down) horror game in game maker. Each player has a flash light which drains overtime. The flashlight uses surfaces to draw light and the cone gets smaller overtime.I would like for the flashlight to act like a real flashlight instead of going through walls. Is there anyway to do this?[Picture of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPBny.png)

Answer (score 0):

how are you currently drawing your flashlight?
I would recommend not drawing a flashlight sprite and instead filling a surface with black (to act as darkness) and cutting your lights out of that.

Then You can use the collision_line function to sweep in an arc from your player and get either where it hits an object or whether the line extends past your flashlight range. Then store all those vertices and draw a primitive with blending to act as flashlight.
Hope that makes sense, otherwise I swear I've seen some posts on the gamemaker forums on this, good luck!